# Showing that there is a zero in extension field

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I have a problem: Show that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and that it has a zero in some simple extension field of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. I started a solution:

we know that since $f(x)= x^2+x+1$ is of degree 2, it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ if it has no zeroes in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Therefore, it can be shown easily by plugging in the only possibilities (0, 1, and 2):

$f(0)=0^2+0+1=1\ne 0$;

$f(1)=1^2+1+1=3\ne 0$;

$f(2)=2^2+2+1=5\ne 0$.

Therefore, we know that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

From here, we will let $\alpha$ be a zero of $x^2+x+1$ in the extension field $(\mathbb{Z}_2(\alpha))[x]$. If we can factor $x^2+x+1$ into 2 linear factors in $(\mathbb{Z}_2(\alpha))[x]$, then we know that the polynomial has a zero in some extension field of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

This is extremely stupid of me, but I am getting stuck at the point of finding the linear factors in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. I know this is the easy part but I can't figure it out. Am I going in the wrong direction on this from the beginning?

Comment: If $\Bbb Z_2=\Bbb Z/2=\Bbb F_2$ is the field with two elements, then its two elements are $0,1$. (And $2:=1+1$ is $0$. So check only $f(0),f(1)\ne 0$.) The linear factors can be forced only over the (unique) field $\Bbb F_4$ with four elements, the elements being $0,1,a,a+1$. (I write $a$ instead of that alpha.) Then of course $(x^2+x+1)=(x-a)(x-(a+1))$.

Comment: @dan_fulea I understand the 0 and 1, that was a stupid mistake on my part. But how did you reach that factorization?

Comment: @batman if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots, then $\alpha+\beta=-1=\text{coeff of } x$. So if $a$ is a root, then the other root is $\beta=-\alpha-1=-a-1=a+1$.

Comment: @AnuragA Isn't the coefficient of x 1 in this case though? Sorry if I'm just being stupid but I don't see where the -1 came from...

Comment: @batman $-1 \equiv 1 \mod 2$

Comment: You might consider editing back in the polynomial whose linear factors you seek!  Cheers!

Comment: Another small correction:  in the paragraph beginning, "From here . . . ", you refer to "the extension field" $(\Bbb Z_2(\alpha))[x]$; that is not a field, it is the ring of polynomials over $\Bbb Z_2(\alpha)$, which *is* a field.  A minor point.  Anyway, ***+1, endorsed!!!***